# How many solutions exists for this equation?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 28$$
I tried to solve it with generating functions.
Is it correct to get to the form of

$${(1 + x + {x^2} + {x^3} + ....)^4}$$

and this equals to:

$${(1 - x)^{ - 4}}$$

and then solve it with binomial expansion ?
Is this correct ?

every question similar to "how many solutions are axsist to this equation?"
can be solved this method?

I know there're a lot of methods and manipulations for this kind of problem.
Can you confirm it's the right path for this kind of problems?

It's like distribute 28 things into 4 objects. 
This is why I used generating functions.

Comment: are you looking for non negative integral solution?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you are asking for how many solutions with $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for each $i$ (where $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$).  If you are looking for real solutions, there are clearly infinitely many.

> The number of integral solutions to $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=n$ with each $x_i\geq 0$ is given as $$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

This can be seen via [stars&bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: yes. I understand it equavilant to D(n,k)
and if the number are negetive ?

Comment: If you allow negative numbers there will be infinitely many.  Suppose you have a solution.  Increasing $ x_1$ by $t $ while decreasing $ x_2$ by $ t $ will also be a solution for any $ t\in\mathbb{Z} $

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the binomial expansion
of $(1-x)^{-4}$ will work.

No, many other type of questions
like this can not be solved
by this method.

Here is a useful expansion:

$(1-x)^{-n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-n}{k}(-x)^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\binom{-n}{k}x^k
$.

And,

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{-n}{k}
&=\frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)...(-n-k+1)}{k!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^k(n)(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k-1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{(n-1)!(n)(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k-1)}{k!(n-1)!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
noting that the
two $(-1)^k$s cancel each other out,
$(1-x)^{-n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{k}x^k
$.

Comment: yes, so all the sums will be positive. thanks